# Using \href instead of \ref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

The link produced by `\ref{defn:First Defined Term}` works fine, but
as I would prefer to have text instead of a number so thought
`\href{defn:First Defined Term}{First Defined Term}` should work, but
it doesn't:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{DefinitionTheorem}

\newenvironment{Definition}[1]{%
    \begin{DefinitionTheorem}
    \label{defn:#1}
}{%
    \end{DefinitionTheorem}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\begin{Definition}{First Defined Term}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Definition}
\lipsum[8-10]

\begin{Definition}{Second Defined Term}
    \lipsum[1]

    \bigskip
     This link works great: \ref{defn:First Defined Term}\par\bigskip
     But this link does not: \href{defn:First Defined Term}{First Defined Term}
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know the `\href` command is only used to link to URLs.

Use `\hyperref` instead:

> `\hyperref[label]{text}`
>
> `text` is made into a link to the same place as
>   `\ref{label}` would be linked.

Adapted to your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Definition]{DefinitionTheorem}

\newenvironment{Definition}[1]{%
    \begin{DefinitionTheorem}
    \label{defn:#1}
}{%
    \end{DefinitionTheorem}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-7]
\begin{Definition}{First Defined Term}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{Definition}
\lipsum[8-10]

\begin{Definition}{Second Defined Term}
    \lipsum[1]

    \bigskip
     This link works great: \ref{defn:First Defined Term}\par\bigskip
     But this link does not: \hyperref[defn:First Defined Term]{First Defined Term}
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following hack.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mylabel[2]{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel%
                             \string{#1\string}%
                             \string{\string{#2\string}%
                                     \string{\thepage\string}\string}}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
  Wow, \mylabel{super}{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
       this is \ref{super}.
\clearpage
  I already told you this is \ref{super} on Page~\pageref{super}.
\end{document}
```